# Как в Excel сделать неизменяемые ячейки?

Tags: excel

Есть ячейка:
А2 = 10

Если в другой ячейке, например Z8, я укажу "взять значение из А2", то нужно, чтобы просто копировалось значение А2.

То есть, при смене значения внутри А2 на 99, например, в другой ячейке, Z8, значение не менялось, а оставалось таким, каким было на момент заполнения = 10.

Comment: Отключить автопересчёт формул.

Comment: ...или скопировать ячейку А2 и с помощью Специальной вставки (Ctrl+Alt+V) вставить её значение в Z8

Comment: ...или простеньким макросом по какой-либо команде заменить формулу на значение

Comment: ...или ввести те же самые `10` в Z8 с клавиатуры - всего три нажатия клавиш, самый быстрый вариант

Comment: не подходят ваши предложения.

Comment: @Sergei Жаль, но именно так работают электронные таблицы (в т.ч и Эксель) - если уж сослался на ячейку, то и будешь получать значение из неё при каждом изменении. Чтобы заставить программу работать иначе, придётся выкручиваться разными нестандартными способами

Comment: @Sergei, что нужно? Ограничение по максимальному значению? Отслеживание определенного числа? Что-то другое?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно ограничить значение в ячейке пороговым значением:

```
=МИН(A2;порог)
```

где *порог* - наибольшее возможное число в ячейке.

Значение "заморозится" только для чисел больше *порога*. При вводе меньшего значения в ячейке отобразится введенное число.